# Is end-to-end encryption possible in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I'm currently researching the possibilities for creating a (peer2peer) messaging client in terms of encryption thus security. This application will be based on web technologies (if possible).

Is end-to-end encryption possible with only JavaScript (client & node.js/peer.js)?

If yes, is it correct to look into the HMAC (RSA) kind of encryption techniques?

The application is going to be a mobile application. The use of web technologies is a bit proof-of-concept.

Comment: Why not just purchase an ssl certificate like everyone else?

Comment: Is the problem solved by implementing a SSL certificate when I am building a (P2P WebRTC) chat application? Maybe I have to add that it will be a mobile (web) application in the future.

Comment: I'm sure you could implement some kind of RSA using  `window.crypto.getRandomValues(uintarr);`, the question is more "would it be good encryption?" and "is it safe?" along with "is the overhead acceptable?"

Comment: @Dominique No, the problem is not solved using only SSL/TLS, because it would only protect client to server to client to client communication. But SSL/TLS is needed to ensure that the attacker cannot change your JavaScript on the fly to subvert the encryption.

Comment: ssl covers client-server comms as mentioned, re: WebRCT there's a quote [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/), *"Encryption is mandatory for all WebRTC components. With RTCDataChannel all data is secured with Datagram Transport Layer Security (DTLS). DTLS is a derivative of SSL, meaning your data will be as secure as using any standard SSL based connection."*

Comment: @Digigizmo Good to know that browsers who support WebRTC already have some kind of security built in. The question then, is that enough? Also because of what I know what SSL secures and the application mostly functions Peer 2 Peer (without server).

Comment: @PaulS. Good points but how would that kind of 'system' be implemented.? And is it still 'needed' if WebRTC already applies DTLS?

Answer (score 9):

The goal of end-to-end encryption is that users can be certain of the security of the communication even if the central server is cheating.  There are two main challenges that need to be solved:

(1) Users need to be 100% certain that they are communicating with whom they think they are communicating.  This is to prevent man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks, where the man-in-the-middle could be anybody including the server itself (example: [Apple iMessage has this weakness](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2015/09/09/lets-talk-about-imessage-again/)).

(2) You need to be 100% sure the client-side code is not cheating.  For example, is it really encrypting the data using the other person's public key, or is it just sending it in the plaintext somewhere else, and then encrypting from there.  Given that whoever has access to the server can swap the JavaScript any time, this is a huge challenge.

Both problems seem solvable.

For (1), users can verify public keys out-of-band, as is done in [PGP/GPG](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x56.html) (unfortunately many people skip this step, but for true end-to-end security, you need it) or [keybase.io](https://keybase.io/docs/server_security/following).

For (2), a group from MIT claims to have solved this in their [Mylar](https://people.csail.mit.edu/nickolai/papers/popa-mylar-2016-08-29.pdf) design.  See section 6.  It should be stated that researchers have found security issues with Mylar, but to my knowledge, their solution to client-side code integrity has not been compromised.

So in theory, end-to-end encryption can be done entirely in JavaScript (what server language is used is not so relevant).  In practice ...  it will not be easy.

Answer (score 5):

You are currently looking at security implementations. If you don't understand the security model & cryptography behind these libraries, your solution will - to a high certainty - not be secure.

Artjom is correct in indicating that for peer to peer encryption you most likely need authentication of both parties. That is not provided by normal SSL/TLS, you'll need client authentication. But for client and server authentication you need to have established *trust*. On normal browsers this is provided by the internal certificate store. It is however much trickier to trust the clients.

All the other stuff (like how RSA is not a HMAC) are implementation details. You should however not be implementing *anything related to security* right now. First focus on your use case, threat scenario and protocol design.

Comment: So you are saying, if I don't know how exactly, just don't do it by myself? I understand that client authentication is a difficult point because we all can never trust the client. Still, do you recommend some stuff I can read or do you think I am overthinking this too much? :P Thank you for your 2 cents of course.

Comment: You first need to establish what you can trust on each location. For most scenarios you don't want just confidentiality, you'll need integrity and authentication as well, as usually man in the middle attacks *are* possible. For transport protocols TLS/DTLS would be the most logical choices, but you will need trusted certificates in most implementations (there is also password based etc.).

Answer (score 2):

At most, you can have "novelty" end-to-end encryption using Javascript in a web browser. That is, it'll look and feel like end-to-end encryption, but the implementation will most likely be scoffed at by cryptographers.

The main reason is that no matter what piece of puzzle you put in to encrypt data on the frontend, your client ultimately depends on what the server sends it.

Required reading:

- https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful//
- http://secushare.org/end2end#header

Comment: javascript does not necessarily mean encryption in the browser.  He listed node.js in the tech stack.